# How can I check the current state of a flow by RPC?

Tags: corda

I've found a  method `recordAuditEvent(...)` inside the `FlowLogic` class, but I can't understand how I can use it and I don't know if it's useful for this use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`recordAuditEvent` is for internal use only.

You can track the progress of a flow using `CordaRPCOps.startTrackedFlowDynamic`. This function returns a `FlowHandle` that has a `progress` property. `progress` is an `Observable` that emits an event for each progress tracker step in the flow. You could use it as follows:

```
val flowHandle = proxy.startTrackedFlowDynamic(MyFlow::class.java, arg1, arg2, ...)

flowHandle.progress.subscribe { progressTrackerLabel ->
    // Log the progress tracker label.
}
```

You can also get the flow's unique run ID via the `FlowHandle`'s `id` property. You can use this ID to check whether the flow is still in progress by checking whether it is still present in the list of current state machines (i.e. flows):

```
val flowInProgress = flowHandle.id in cordaRPCOps.stateMachinesSnapshot().map { it.id }
```

You can also monitor the state machine manager to wait until the flow completes, then check whether it was successful and get its result:

```
val flowUpdates = cordaRPCOps.stateMachinesFeed().updates
flowUpdates.subscribe {
    if (it.id == flowHandle.id && it is StateMachineUpdate.Removed) {
        val int = it.result.getOrThrow()
        // Handle result.
    }
}
```