# How to log progress in Corda?

Tags: logging, corda

https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.5/flow-state-machines.html#progress-tracking talks about how to use the `ProgressTracker` API but doesn't say how to view its output.

I gather its output is written to the terminal when a flow is started from the CRaSH shell.

Can it be configured to be written anywhere else, e.g. to a node's log file?

Or is this only ever visible on the client side, e.g. using the `startTrackedFlowDynamic` API like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48147337/49942):

```
val flowHandle = proxy.startTrackedFlowDynamic(MyFlow::class.java, arg1, arg2, ...)

flowHandle.progress.subscribe { progressTrackerLabel ->
    // Log the progress tracker label.
}
```

Writing and maintaining other (non-Corda) server-side code, I've been used to using log files. Is it conventional to use log messages when writing CorDapps, i.e. to write code which logs a CorDapp's routine progress and any exceptional events?

Comment: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.5/node-administration.html#logging

Comment: Thank you but that doesn't answer either question: i.e. whether it's possible to log progress tracker states, and whether it's conventional to write CorDapp-specific log messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ProgressTracker` is supposed to provide information to a client side regarding the progress of a particular flow.

Its always good to have logging in your Cordapps. I don't think there is any specific configuration to dump to ProgressTracker steps to a log file, but you could always have log statements to do the same.

Comment: Thank you. Can you point to any example of implementing logging in a CorDapp? Would you hope to write to the same log file as the node, or, into a separate CorDapp-specific log file?

Comment: I don't have an example handy, but its nothing different from a general java application. Corda uses log4j for logging. To have separate logging file for the cordapp you can have the configuration in the log4j config file, like separate logger and appenders for your cordapp packages.